# Modify hotkey to only fire when text area not in focus

Tags: autohotkey

Below script fires sublime text program when user types "sub" :

```
:*:sub::   ;
Run "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" 
return
```

The issue is that it also fires as im typing text into a text area such as a word document, notepad or anywhere text can be typed. Can the script be modified so that it just fires when a text area is not in focus ?

Comment: Why the hell you want press 3 keys when you can make shorter hotkey with CTRL,SHIFT and etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
:*b0:sub::
Sleep, 200
ControlGetText, OutputVar,,A
;MsgBox, %OutputVar%
;StringMid, a,OutputVar,StrLen(OutputVar)-2, 3
;MsgBox, %a%
;if not a="sub"
if not InStr(OutputVar,"sub")
    Run "notepad" 
return
```

This works very badly, but works in notepad. Issue with ControlGetText can't retrieve text(wrong control,strange encoding) from most apps or i use it wrong. 
in [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) ControlGetText("[Active]","","") retrieve text alot better.